# Testing apache poi generating excel content

Tags: java, excel, junit, apache-poi

I have a problem with testing apache poi generating excel method. My method returns Resource (org.springframework.core.io.Resource) and now i want to cast this to for example InputStream to create Workbook and test content file. How to do that?

For now i tested only if file exists but not content :

```
ResponseEntity<Resource> response = myService.createExcel();
ByteArrayResource responseBody = (ByteArrayResource) response.getBody();
assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
assertThat(responseBody).isNotNull();
assertThat(responseBody.contentLength()).isGreaterThan(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no choice but parse the content with POI again just like your server end had done.